# Testing angular 6 promise injection

Tags: angular, testing, promise

I trying to make a test in angular but i've got some problems.
i have the code bellow:

```
//LojasService code:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Lojas } from './lojas';

@Injectable()
export class LojasServices{

constructor(private http : HttpClient){

}

todasLojas(): Promise<Lojas[]>{

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

        this.http.get<Lojas[]>('http://localhost:3000/todasLojas')
        .subscribe(
            (s: Lojas[]) => resolve(s),
            (err) =>  reject(err)
        );

    });

}}
  //here is the test class
describe('Lojas Services', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [LojasServices]
    });

});

it('should return a the correct value', inject([LojasServices], (service: LojasServices)=>{

 service.todasLojas().then(a => {
    console.log('loggin');
    expect(a.length).toBe(3);
  }).catch(s => {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
  });

 }));
```

I see other solutions on internet but i couldn't find them helpful. Trying to use  "async" before the inject but still it did not help.

Comment: You should have shared your service code snippet too, that will help others in knowing what is going to be tested. and also share the error that you are getting

Comment: Did my answer below help you with the issues you were having?

Answer (score 1):

I see two main problems with your code as-is:

- While you are not calling a back-end service since you are importing `HttpClientTestingModule`, you don't actually set that up anywhere.  There is extensive documentation available for this here: [Testing HTTP Requests](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests).  However, to test such a simple service, I would not go to all that trouble, the `get()` method is quite simple to mock.
- The second major issue is that you are not waiting for the promise to resolve in your spec (the 'it' function).  This is solved by wrapping the callback with `async`.

I have this running in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53672234?file=app%2Fmy.service.spec.ts) for you.

From that Stackblitz, here is the .spec's `describe()`:

```
describe('Lojas Services', () => {
    const mockReturnValue: Lojas[] = [1, 2, 3]; // change this!
    const httpSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
    httpSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(mockReturnValue));

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            // imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ], <-- this is commented out
            providers: [ LojasServices, 
                {provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpSpy} // <-- this uses the spy instead of HttpClient
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should return the correct value', async(inject([LojasServices], (service: LojasServices)=>{
        service.todasLojas()
            .then(a => {
                console.log('loggin');
                expect(a.length).toBe(3);
            })
            .catch(s => {
                expect(true).toBe(false);
            });
    })));
});
```

Yes, I changed your indentations - that is purely personal preference.  :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LojasServices } from './test.service';

describe('Lojas Services', () => {
    let service: LojasServices;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;


    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [LojasServices]
        });

        service = TestBed.get(LojasServices);
        httpTestingController= TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // After every test, assert that there are no more pending requests.
        httpTestingController.verify();
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should return a the correct value',() => {
        service.todasLojas().then( a => {
            expect(a.length).toBe(3);
        }, err => {
            expect(err).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: i try this but when i  put the httpTestingController it not recognized, so i create a variable of type HttpTestingController but not work too.

Comment: updated code, You need to import HttpTestingController  from `@angular/common/http/testing';`
Also if possible share your service that you are trying to test

Comment: i update the code and i edited the code with the service.

Comment: Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET http://localhost:3000/todasLojas 
with this is possible to say that the promise not respond yet?

Comment: is your local service running? If not you need to mock the service call using spy

Comment: yes, it's local. I can't use without mock the data?

Comment: You can if you have it running locally else the best practice is to spy and mock the response and verify the result and make sure the call is being made using httpTestingController

Comment: @nkuma_12 - I find is better to code up an answer as an example in something like Stackblitz so there isn't so much back-and-forth as you try to correct your mistakes.  :)